# Make Guzzle request but dont wait for response

Tags: php, guzzle, php-7.0

at the moment I am making a very simple call to an API

```
$result = $this->client->post('http://localhost:8000'.'/'.$this->file->type, [
    'form_params' => [
        'file' => $storagePath
    ]
]);
```

This all works great, just one major problem.  The API route it is calling runs some algorithms on a huge data set, so the request can take up to 4 hours.  Obviously I do not want the user having to keep their browser open for this long until the request completes.

Is there any way I can just make the API call almost like a trigger.  I make the POST call with the data, and then the request ends.  The API can then do all it needs to, and instead of sending back a response object, it could trigger an API I set up to pass back the processed data into a database?

Really, just looking at suggestions as to how I can send data to an API and not wait hours for it to process?

Thanks

Comment: You could try setting a very short [connect_timeout](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#connect-timeout) or [read_timeout](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#read-timeout).

Comment: Is the script on the same server you are sending request from?

Comment: You should absolutely never try to keep an HTTP session open for _four hours_. Ideally the initial call should return something like an ID so that the status can be polled periodically and results retrieved with a later, separate request.

Comment: dispatch a job seem ok

Comment: Yes, both scripts are on same server